# Sharepoint Visual studio workflow

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, visual

I am new to developing apps in Visual Studio for SP. I have a problem to use the standard functions for creating a workflow. Currently I need the workflow action `Set field in current item`, but I don't know where to find this action. Which action in VS is the replacement for that action? I was trying to use the `Update list item` action too, but it asks me for a C# expression, how to write the placeholders for the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use the `UpdateListItem` activity.

In the `ListItemPropertiesDynamicValue` property you need to set the `Path` and the `Value`. In `Path` select the field  you want to update. In `Value` enter the value you want the field to be.

So, for example, if you want a field called `Status` - which is a Single Line of Text field - to be set to "In Progress" it would look something like this:

[image]

If the field you want to update was a Number field, then you would simply enter a number in `Value`.

But remember in the `Value` field you can also enter the name of a workflow variable, if you've defined any.

**Update:**

It seems you're asking how to assign a workflow variable to the workflow item's ID.

First you need the item ID. Use the `GetCurrentItemId` activity:

[image]

In this activity's properties set the `Result` property to a workflow variable of your choice, I've created one called `itemId`:

[image]

Then you need the `Assign` activity:

[image]

And set its properties like so:

[image]

`WorkflowID` will be assigned to the value of `itemId`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found that way, but I don't know how to put in the Value field a placeholder. For example. I need to set in one column the ID of the item. In SPD I would use the Set field in current item action and set MyField to CurrentItem:ID.

Comment: Are you saying you have a workflow variable called `MyField` or something else and you want to take the value of this workflow variable and use it to set the value of a column in your list item? If so, in the `Value` field in the screenshot above just enter the name of your variable.

Comment: For my example I need to set the ID of the item to the field "MyField". On your screenshot MyField should be in the Path column and the ID of the item should be in the Value column.

Comment: That's correct. But, do you know that the `ID` column of a list item is read only? You can't update it.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstandings, I need the opposite. Here is a screenshot from SPD from the action that I need. http://imgur.com/thxyA0C

Comment: Ah, that's completely different. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hello, seems that this is the answer that I need, but I got some errors that the columns doesn't exist. http://imgur.com/bL9Yjpa

Comment: They aren't columns, they are workflow variables. Did you create those workflow variables first? In your second image you can see a tab called Variables. Click that and check if Visual Studio has created the variables for you. If not, create them. And double check the scope of the variables.

Comment: Ok, now I understood that it uses the custom made variables. But ok, now the two variables are filled with the ID from the item. But how to add that information to the item column WorkflowId? I ended up like this, but it doesn't work: http://imgur.com/JPlFltT

Comment: Your settings look fine, it should work. By the way, you don't really need the `WorkflowId` workflow variable if you've already put the item ID in the `ItemID` workflow variable. Just set your `WorkflowId` column to the `ItemID` workflow variable in the `UpdateListItem` activity.

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to set the WorkflowID column to be a Number Type. That's weird because in SPD you can assign the ID to a single line text column. Is it possible to convert the values? Btw, thank you for your solution, it helped me alot.

Comment: I think you needed to set your `WorkflowId` column to be Number because your `WorkflowId` workflow variable was of `Int32` type. You could have also left the `WorkflowId` column as Single line of text and just changed your `WorkflowId` workflow variable from `Int32` to `String`. You're welcome :)